# Is it possible to revert to Windows

Tags: windows

Is it possible to go back to Windows if I already completely replaced it with Ubuntu 13.04?

After using Ubuntu, I decided it just wasn't for me :-( , so now I'm wanting to put Microsoft Windows back onto my computer.

Is there any way for me to get Windows back?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, If you have backups.
When you bought your computer you might have have been given a OEM key. With that you can also download windows and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need help finding your DVD image, you can go to the computer manufacturers website (i.e. Dell.com) and call tech support for an iso build, you need to tell them a number located somewhere on the computer and you also need to tell them the operating system (i.e. Windows 7 Professional) and it's product key (OEM key which user320 mentioned). After you have given tech suport your info they can build an iso and you can burn it to a DVD, the you can get rid of Ubuntu 13.04 and put Windows back on. I hope this information is useful to you.